# When I run this code it repetitively rolls over and over again. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

min = 1
max = 6

roll_again = "yes"

while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
    print ("Rolling Dice...")
    print ("The number is...")
    print (random.randint(min, max))
    print (random.randint(min, max))

roll_again = raw_input("Want to roll again?");
```

Comment: Check your indentation.

Comment: It is indented correctly but when I paste the code on here it makes it look all messed up.

Comment: No, seriously. Check your indentation.

Comment: For next time: About the code indentation on stack overflow, select the code and press ctrl + k. And read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting please.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the user input is in the while loop, otherwise `roll_again` is permanently set to `"yes"` and you are stuck in an infinite loop.

```
import random

min = 1
max = 6

roll_again = "yes"

while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
    print ("Rolling Dice...")
    print ("The number is...")
    print (random.randint(min, max))
    print (random.randint(min, max))
    roll_again = raw_input("Want to roll again?");
```

And the following is a more pythonic approach

```
import random

min = 1
max = 6

while True:
    print ("Rolling Dice...")
    print ("The number is...")
    print (random.randint(min, max))
    print (random.randint(min, max))
    roll_again = input("Want to roll again?");
    if roll_again != "yes" and roll_again != "y":
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're setting your loop to always be "yes". Thus its looping over and over and over until it becomes false which it will not.

Try this:

```
import random
while True:
    min = 1
    max = 6

    roll_again = input("Do you want to roll again? Type: Yes or y")

    if roll_again.lower() == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
        print ("Rolling Dice...")
        print ("The number is...")
        print (random.randint(min, max))
```

This code will promt a user everytime after the roll to see if they want to roll again.

Comment: inconsistent use of tabs or spaces in indentation